# No horizontal scrollbar in kiln code reviews

Tags: kiln

Sometimes in Kiln I get a horizontal scrollbar for files with long lines of code, but most of the time I don't. This is all in IE9.

Is there any way to fix this or force horizontal scrollbars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only get a horizontal scroll bar when the lines extend off the side of the page.

Comment: These lines certainly do extend off the page. Still no scrollbar.

Comment: That's no good. Thanks for the bug report. I'll get it fixed up for the next release. In the meantime, resizing the browser window should cause the scrollbars to appear.

Comment: Very good. If you need screenshots or additional info, please let me know.

Comment: We upgraded to Fog Creek Platform Version 8.8.39.0 (DB 798, Build 0) and now get horizontal scrollbars when lines extend off the side of the page.